# In postfix how can I conditionally enforce check_sender_access

Tags: postfix, domain, virtualhost, email-server, blacklist

I am servicing 2 virtual domains: domain1.org , domain2.org. I want to enforce the following policy:

If a client connects **from an IP address in $mynetworks** then I want to **allow only mails** for which  the **sender** address domain **belongs** to one of my domains.

If a client connects **from any other IP address** then I want to **allow only mails** for which  the **sender** address domain **does not belong** to one of my domains.

For that have two hash access files (sender_for_local_clients and sender_for_remote_clients)

sender_for_local_clients contains

```
domain1.org OK
domain2.org OK
```

sender_for_remote_clients contains

```
domain1.org REJECT
domain2.org REJECT
```

But I dont know how to combine them in the smtpd_sender_restrictions directive. Part of the problem is that the OK actions do not automatically PERMIT, while REJECT actions do automatically REJECT, so I cant find a proper sequence of smtpd_sender_restrictions that will accomplish my above stated policy. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You will need a restriction class for this. Reproduce the contents of $mynetworks to a CIDR map, e.g. cidr:/etc/postfix/local_clients with something like this:

```
# local networks
192.168.0.0/24 local_senders

smtpd_restriction_classes = local_senders
local_Senders = check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_for_local_clients, reject

smtpd_recipient_restrictions = 
 ...
 check_client_access cidr:/etc/postfix/local_clients
 ...
 check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/sender_for_remote_clients
 ...
```